# Customized Message queue for holding requests for retry

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jboss

I'm building a custom message queue, where I have to maintain a queue to hold the requests and retry them using a queue structure(FIFO). I have started out using servlets, which actually maintains the queue during the server life time and when server goes down, it will tranfers all these requests to the DB table.

In this case, I can I send a request to destination using a web service call? Can anyone please show me elaborately on how to use a web service call to post a request object in the servlet. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Message Drive Bean ? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpl.html

Comment: What is your exact Problem? Building a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)? Or processing that queue?

Comment: @Fildor : Precisely, Both. Since there should be an option of proxying the WS call and use it if it fails to be accepted by the next layer.

Comment: @Fildor : Is there any way, I can create a web service call to post a request to the destination??